# UrlRewriteFilter skipping i18n Interceptor in Struts 2

Tags: struts2, internationalization, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I managed to have struts 2 i18n Interceptor working to change the session locale. It's working if I call directly to the Action, for example:

```
https://localhost:8443/loadClientLogin.action?request_locale=fr
```

But if I use UrlRewriteFilter to map from a rule, it calls to the action, but it seems that 18n interceptor is skipped, since locale is not changed.

This is the url rewriter's rule I wrote for this action:

```
<rule>
    <from>^/client/login(\??)(.*)$</from>
    <to type="forward">/loadClientLogin.action$1$2</to>
</rule>
```

And this is the url I use to change the locale:

```
https://localhost:8443/client/login?request_locale=fr
```

By other side, if I change the type of the rule to "redirect" it works, but then the browser address show the "ugly" forwarded url.

It's strange that other custom interceptor I use to manage user session it's called always.

**UPDATE:**

I put a log trace in my Action that write the locale from session:

```
public String loadClientLogin() {
    logger.debug("locale: " + ActionContext.getContext().getLocale());
    return Action.SUCCESS;
}
```

When I call directly to the Action, the log shows the correct locale code:

```
locale: fr
```

But through the url rewriter I get this:

```
locale: [ljava.lang.string;@4d227ffb
```

Any suggestion will be very appreciated.

Comment: Remove this filter, you can map you actions directly.

Comment: @RomanC Yes, I know. and probably it makes sense in this particular example, but I need it in other sections of the app for SEO reasons (for mapping id parameters to url paths, for example).

Comment: But, probably you don't know how to use wildcard mapping in advanced.

Comment: I'm quite new to Struts 2. I'll take a look to that. Thank you.